# Solving $\int X_s \, ds = B_1$ where $B$ is a Brownian motion

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion. I am interested in the equation

$$\int_0^1 X_s \, ds = B_1 \quad a.s$$

Besides the obvious solution $X_s=B_1$ for all $s\in [0,1]$, how can we come up with solutions ? Can we characterize in a nice way the set of solutions ? Are all solutions of the form $B_1 f(s)$ with $\int_0^1 f(s) \, ds =1$ ? If so, how can we prove it ?

With each solution $X_s$, we associate the value $V_X= \int_0^1 E[X_s^2]\,ds$. Among all solutions, is it true that the one that minimizes $V_X$ is $X_s = B_1 $ and is unique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, trivially, every solution is of the form $X_s = B_1 + Y_s$ where $\int_0^1 Y_s\,ds =0$ a.s., so this reduces to characterizing processes whose time integral is zero.  I can't think of any "nicer" way to characterize the latter set.

In particular, it is certainly not true that every solution is of the form $X_s = B_1 f(s)$; for example take $X_s = B_1 + \sin(2\pi s)$.

It is true that $X_s = B_1$ is the unique minimizer of $V_X$.  Note that $V_X$ is just the squared norm in the Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega \times [0,1])$.  If $Y_s$ satisfies $\int Y_s\,ds = 0$, then by Fubini's theorem
$$\int_0^1 E[B_1 Y_s]\,ds = E\left[B_1 \int_0^1 Y_s\,ds\right] = 0$$
so that $B_1$ is orthogonal to $Y_s$.  Hence by the Pythagorean theorem, if $X_s = B_1 + Y_s$ we have $\|X\|^2 = \|B_1\|^2 + \|Y\|^2$, or in your notation, $V_X = 1 + V_Y$.  So this is clearly minimized iff $Y=0$.

Comment: Shouldn't $X_s$ be of the form $Z_s B_1 + Y_s$ with $\int_0^1 Z_s ds =1$ a.s and $\int_0^1 Y_s ds=0$ a.s ?

Comment: @W.Volante: That is already of the form I described: write $X_s = B_1 + ((Z_s-1)B_1 + Y_s)$.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.